# ksoap Propertyinfo type change

Tags: android, soap, service, web, ksoap

I have one small problem which i can't solve. By default, propertyingo value is anyType:

```
 <n1:Role i:type="d:anyType">
```

how can I change this type to a:User ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right you can just use setType method:You create your PropertyInfo object and then just set your custom type in your code:

```
 PropertyInfo role = new PropertyInfo();
role.setType(User.class);
```

Or another way is to assign your custom type (an instance of Class) to the `type` field of the `PropertyInfo`:

`role.type = User.Class;`